# Birt : How I can generate attachments that are stored in Postgres table

Tags: birt, birt-deapi

How Can I create Birt report that will have links to files that can be downloaded by user.

For ex : I have Postgres table that contains following files data(file content stored as bytea)

---

### filename    mimetype           filecontent(bytea)

### file.pdf    apple/octet-stream

It contains all the file types(doc, csv, xls jpeg, png etc)

I need to create report that shows all the attachment details and also link to download them.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a link is easy by using the dynamic text item with content type HTML and constructing an  element inside.

Comment: How can I render files[all file types] stored in database. Whats the best approach for such file rendering in birt

Comment: That's a different question and beyond the scope of BIRT.